# angular Library install peerDependencies in Host Application

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, node-modules, angular-library

I have an Angular Library which has some peerDependencies

```
{  "name": "ui",
  "version": "1.1.18",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "wijmo": "^5.20211.794",
    "@grapecity/wijmo.angular2.all": "^5.20211.794",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^9.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^28.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^28.1.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^28.1.3",
    "ngx-mask": "13.1.15",
    "subsink": "^1.0.2",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

what i need to achive is when i install my angular library in a host angular application using `npm i`
these peer dependencies automaticly installed on the host application
and no need to reference these packages on the host application

Comment: `npm` does install the peerDeps by default.

Comment: thank you for your response i have been struggling along time to solve this, the problem was my global npm config,the legacy-peer-deps option was set to true .